# html5 - Hold page background color even after page refresh using local storage

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I want to keep a background color value even after page refresh. I think it is possible with html5 localstorage or jquery ajax.can you please help me out to make this things.

Below is the code that i've tried so far:

HTML

```
<ul class="chngeme">
    <li class="red"></li>
    <li class="blue"></li>
    <li class="green"></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('ul.chngeme li').click(function() {
    var getcolor = $(this).css('background-color');

    $('body').css('background', getcolor);

    if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
        // Store
        localStorage.setItem('colorvalue', getcolor);

        // Retrieve
        document.getElementById('body').style.setProperty = localStorage.getItem('colorvalue');
    }else {
        document.getElementById('result').style.setProperty = 'Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...!';
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't seem like you encountered any problem yet. Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: <ul class="chngeme">
         <li class="red"></li>
            <li class="blue"></li>
            <li class="green"></li>
</ul>

Comment: $('ul.chngeme li').click(function(){
  //alert('hi');
  
  var getcolor=$(this).css('background-color');
  
  //alert(getcolor); 
  $('body').css('background',getcolor);
  
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("colorvalue",getcolor);
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("body").style.setProperty = localStorage.getItem("colorvalue");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").style.setProperty = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
  
 });

Comment: @SudipBose you can add the code by editing the question. Comments section is a not a better place for multiple line codes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the value when the user clicks on the `li`. But you have to retrieve the value when the page/document loads.

Use the below code snippet:

HTML

```
<ul class="chngeme">
    <li class="red"></li>
    <li class="blue"></li>
    <li class="green"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.red {
    background-color: #f00;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #00f;
}

.green {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

JS

```
$('ul.chngeme li').click(function() {
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');

    $('body').css('background-color', color);

    if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
        // Store
        localStorage.setItem('colorvalue', color);
    }else {
        $('#result').html('Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...!');
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
        // Retrieve
        var color = localStorage.getItem('colorvalue');

        $('body').css('background-color', color);
    }else {
        $('#result').html('Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...!');
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7moorthi/bqwhwrv6/